# linux + get errors about libraries in spite of already installed lib rpms

Tags: linux, compiling, vpn, libraries

I downloaded the vpnc client from the following link

```
   https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~massar/vpnc/
```

Then I installed the vpnc on my Linux red-hat machine ( version 6.x ) as the following:

```
tar zxf vpnc-0.5.3.tar.gz
cd vpnc-0.5.3
make
```

.

```
make
make: libgcrypt-config: Command not found
gcc -O3 -g -W -Wall -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings  -DVERSION=\"0.5.3\"   -c -    o isakmp-pkt.o isakmp-pkt.c
In file included from isakmp-pkt.c:31:
math_group.h:38:20: error: gcrypt.h: No such file or directory
In file included from isakmp-pkt.c:31:
math_group.h:62: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before âgcry_mpi_tâ
In file included from vpnc.h:24,
             from isakmp-pkt.c:32:
tunip.h:43: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before âgcry_cipher_hd_tâ
isakmp-pkt.c: In function âparse_isakmp_packetâ:
isakmp-pkt.c:823: warning: format â%dâ expects type âintâ, but argument 2 has type     âsize_tâ
make: *** [isakmp-pkt.o] Error 1
```

Why I get errors about libgcrypt and libgcrypt? Those rpm’s are already installed on my machine, so what's the problem here?

I checked the rpm's: and they installed on my Linux machine

```
rpm -qa | grep libgcrypt
libgcrypt-1.4.5-9.el6_2.2.x86_64
libgcrypt-1.4.5-9.el6_2.2.i686


rpm -qa | grep gcrypt
libgcrypt-1.4.5-9.el6_2.2.x86_64
libgcrypt-1.4.5-9.el6_2.2.i686
```

remark - the link below described the vpnc installation:

http://floppsie.comp.glam.ac.uk/Glamorgan/gaius/networks/13.html

Answer (score 1):

You must have missed step two that says you need the `libgcrypt-devel` package installed.

`yum install libgcrypt-devel`.  You only have the compiled library installed for binaries that are linked against it; you do not have the development packages that allow you to build your own binaries against it.